# Get Action Index (or contract) from inside notification

Tags: smart-contract

Is there a way to get the index (ordinal) of the current action that is being processed?

If you could access `apply_context` you could do `get_action_id()` but afaik that isn't exposed inside an action.

What I would like is to be able to know the contract that is being executed that I'm being notified of inside a notification handler like `[[eosio::on_notify("*::transfer")]]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible atm.

Looking at the [intrinsics_def.hpp](https://github.com/eosnetworkfoundation/mandel.cdt/blob/main/libraries/native/native/eosio/intrinsics_def.hpp) in the cdt, there is no intrinsic to get the action_ordinal of an action called. Pretty sure this is the place where it would be found if there was such functionallity.

Comment: Maybe worth opening a issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get the contract the notification originated from, you can use `get_first_receiver()` but I'd still like to know if it's possible to get the action ordinal, so, if anybody knows, please respond